# Windows Phone ResourceLoader loads empty strings

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, resources, winrt-xaml

I develop a Windows Phone 8.1 application and I need to put my string resources into separate assembly. I created a PCL project named "Resources" and put my localized string into files 
/Strings/Resources.lang-en-US.resw (for US culture), /Strings/Resources.lang-ru-RU.resw (for RU culture), /Strings/Resources.resw (for culture independent string resources).
Unfortunately following code returns an empty string:

```
var resourceLoader = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView("Resources");
return resourceLoader.GetString("some_key");
```

I also cannot access resources in xaml by using x:Uid attribute.
Can anybody help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured.
It was a mistake in resource map parameter in GetForCurrentView method. It should be "Resources/Resources", where the 1st Resources is the asssembly name while the 2nd stands for first part of resorce file names.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue however I can get the string from C# (with the Get String) but using the x:Uid doesn't seem to work.... whe you said you've figured it out, did you also the the Uid working?